# Logic with necessity and sufficiency

Tags: logic

(I think the title is appropriate)
Given a statement S, "if there is a funnel cloud at a location, then the sirens are sounding." Can I use S to show that there is a funnel cloud? Can I use S to show that there is no funnel cloud?

If I suppose S is true, are either of these two statements true: a) If the sirens are not sounding, there must be no funnel cloud at that location.  b) If there is no funnel cloud at that location, then the sirens are not sounding.

Comment: (a) True, (b) False

Comment: Relabel the proposition X, then define F = "there is a funnel cloud" and S = "sirens are sounding." In order to answer your questions, figure out which of these four are consistent with X and which aren't: $$F \wedge S \qquad F \wedge \neg S \qquad \neg F \wedge S \qquad \neg F \wedge \neg S$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part (a) is certainly true; in fact, it is called the contrapositive. Given any statement $P \rightarrow Q$ that is true, $\neg Q \rightarrow \neg P$ is also true. Part (b) need not be true; it is the converse and looks like $\neg P \rightarrow \neg Q$.

Maybe this parallel example will help. We know the following is true: "If it is snowing, it is cold." If we say $P$ is "It is snowing," and $Q$ is "It is cold," this is of the form $P \rightarrow Q$.

Just by common sense we know that "If it is not cold, it is not snowing" is true, and this is in fact the contrapositive $\neg Q \rightarrow \neg P$. However, "If it is not snowing, it is not cold" need not be true (it can be cold but not snowing), and that is the converse ($\neg P \rightarrow \neg Q$).

Arguing by the converse is not valid, but arguing by the contrapositive is fine and is sometimes the most straightforward way to go about proving a hypothesis in the first place.

Consider the hypothesis "If $X$ is a square, $X$ is a rectangle." If we can show that if $X$ is not a rectangle, it **cannot** be a square, we have also proven the original hypothesis.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know, thank you.